# Association Mining - Apriori: can it handle multiple attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, apriori

Association Rules using Apriori - is what I have been exploring for identifying shopping patterns.
All the examples that I see online consider only one attribute "Product" and nothing else.
How do I handle a dataset of multiple attributes and apply appriori to it to extract patterns.
Please help..
Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

As long as all attributes are categorical this should not be a problem.
An example how it could work:

Data:

```
[Age: 30-39; Gender: M; Products: [Apple, Beer]]
[Age: 50-59; Gender: F; Products: [Chocolate, Cherries]]
[Age: 30-39; Gender: F; Products: [Apple]]
[Age: 10-19; Gender: F; Products: [Chocolate]]
```

would yield the frequent patterns like

```
[{Gender: F}, Support: 3]
[{Age: 30-39}, Support: 2]
[{Age: 30-39; Product: Apple}, Support: 2]
[{Gender: F; Product: Chocolate}, Support: 2]
```

For the actual implementation, the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) on the Apriori algorithm is ok. But the concept is really simple, just count item set occurrences of increasing length.